# Why does all Angular 2 ng-boostrap Modal code have to be at top in app.module.ts?

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap

Long-time .Net/C#/JavaScript/others coder, just now learning Angular 2. I'm having a hard time keeping ng2-bootstrap Modal code/logic where I *think* it belongs. In my mind it makes no sense to be forced to import and include all the Modal login code in the top level app.module.ts. I want to move it down into game.module.ts (where it's actually used). However, the only way I can get the Modal to work is if everything is up at the top in app.module.ts.

If you notice anything below that is dumb or bad practice, I'd definitely appreciate it you would point it out. I'm just learning A2 :-)

Here is an example of what **does work** for me...

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// src/app/app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <a routerLink="/home">Home</a> |
        <a routerLink="/game">Game</a>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
export class AppComponent { }


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// src/app/app.module.ts

import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { GameComponent } from './game.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './not-found.component';
import { LoginModalComponent, LoginModalContent } from './login-modal.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'game', component: GameComponent },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        JsonpModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        GameComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent,
        LoginModalComponent,
        LoginModalContent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [LoginModalContent]
})
export class AppModule { }


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// src/app/home.component.ts

import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <p>
                This is the HOME screen.
            </p>
        </div>
    `
})
export class HomeComponent {
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule {
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// src/app/game.component.ts

import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <template ngbModalContainer></template>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <p>
                This is the GAME screen.
            </p>
            <hr>
            <login-modal-button></login-modal-button>
        </div>
    `
})
export class GameComponent {

}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        GameComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [GameComponent]
})
export class GameModule {

}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// src/app/login-model.component.ts

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
    template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there! Please login...</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
    </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
    `
})
export class LoginModalContent {
    @Input() name;

    constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'login-modal-button',
    template: `<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open()">Open the modal</button>`
})
export class LoginModalComponent {
    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

    open() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(LoginModalContent);
        modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
    }
}
```

Following is how I'm *trying* to build the app because it makes more sense to me that the Login Modal stuff should be under game.component.ts where it's actually used.

Here is an example of what does **NOT work** (error at bottom) for me. The only changes are moving the Login Modal pieces out of AppModule down into GameModule...

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// src/app/app.module.ts

import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { GameComponent } from './game.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './not-found.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'game', component: GameComponent },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        JsonpModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        GameComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// src/app/game.component.ts

import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginModalComponent, LoginModalContent } from './login-modal.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <template ngbModalContainer></template>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <p>
                This is the GAME screen.
            </p>
            <hr>
            <login-modal-button></login-modal-button>
        </div>
    `
})
export class GameComponent {

}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        GameComponent,
        LoginModalComponent,
        LoginModalContent
    ],
    bootstrap: [GameComponent],
    entryComponents: [LoginModalContent]
})
export class GameModule {

}
```

This is the error in Chrome console with above code...

[image]

Comment: Well, you are confusing.. you're using `ng-bootstrap`, not `ng2-bootstrap`. Tag/Modify the title accordingly.

Comment: Where is your component which has `login-modal-button` selector?

Comment: @yurzui it's in game.component.ts template in both examples

Comment: @developer033 You're right, sorry. I fixed the post.

Comment: To whoever down voted the post: Please explain?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Remove `GameComponent` from `declarations` array of your `AppModule`

2) Import `GameModule` to `AppModule`

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        JsonpModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        GameModule  // <== this line
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3) Import `NgbModalModule` to `GameModule` to do `ngbModalContainer` directive working

**game.module.ts**

```
import { NgbModalModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    imports: [NgbModalModule], // <== this line
    declarations: [
        GameComponent,
        LoginModalComponent,
        LoginModalContent
    ],
    bootstrap: [GameComponent],
    entryComponents: [LoginModalContent]
})
export class GameModule {}
```

I also recommend you to read these two articles:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html

Comment: Thanks for the examples and links! I think I read those at some point but clearly I did not ready *carefully* :-( From the first link: This I think sums up what I missed...

*As the app grows, we refactor the root module into feature modules that represent collections of related functionality. We then import these modules into the root module.*